# Fetching PHP data in ionic 3 Frontend

Tags: php, html, angular, typescript, ionic3

We are facing issue in displaying data in ionic 3, where data is coming from PHP REST.

Below is my angular code to get data:

```
this.auth.displayinformation(this.customer_info.cid).subscribe(takecusinfo => {
    if(takecusinfo){
        this.storecusinfo = takecusinfo;
        console.log("store customer info", this.storecusinfo);
    }
})
```

Console Output:

```
{0: "6", 1: "200", 2: "4"}
```

I want this to be displayed in ionic3 HTML. Please suggest me.

Answer (score 0):

You can display them in HTML by doing this, say you want to display them in `ion-card`

```
  <ion-card>
    <ion-card-content>
      {{storecusinfo}}
    </ion-card-content>
  </ion-card>
```

Comment: I want particular something like this {{storecusinfo.0}} value so only "6" should be displayed on the front-end.

Answer (score 0):

You can turn your object to an array then display it:

```
 this.auth.displayinformation(this.customer_info.cid).subscribe(takecusinfo => {

            if(takecusinfo){
                for(let index in takecusinfo) { 
                  this.storecusinfo.push(object[index]); 
              }
                console.log("store customer info", this.storecusinfo);
            }
        })
```

#### in html

```
<ion-card>
    <ion-card-content>
      <p *ngFor="let item of storecusinfo"> {{item}} </p>
    </ion-card-content>
  </ion-card>
```

Answer (score 0):

In .ts file

```
this.auth.displayinformation(this.customer_info.cid).subscribe(takecusinfo => {
    if(takecusinfo){
        this.storecusinfo = Object.keys(takecusinfo);
        console.log("store customer info", this.storecusinfo);
    }
})
```

In .html

```
  <ion-list margin-bottom>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let key of storecusinfo">
    {{storecusinfo[key]}}
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can convert this object into Array and loop through it, by values method or map Iterator for more control and validation.
it will return an array of values.

```
 var obj = {0: "6", 1: "200", 2: "4"};

 // with mapping
 this.data =  Object.keys(obj).map(key => obj[key]);
 this.value =  Object.values(obj);
 // output : ["6", "200", "4"]
```

in HTML

```
 <ul>
      <li *ngFor='let val of values'>{{val}}</li>
 </ul>
```